Ubuntu wont boot from sdxc card reader slot of 2012 macbook
I have an old 2012 macbook pro with ubuntu OS installed on a micro sd (not the installer for ubuntu, the actual os like it was a hard disk).
When i boot using the micro sd using a usb converter it works normally but when i use the micro sd with the sd card reader it sents me to Busybox and it says "UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell"

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details; so we can't give specific advice. The file-system table of your OS tells it to use a specific device/partition with UUID matching what was required; that device is listed as mandatory but it couldn't be found; thus the dropping to shell. The required device has been removed (deleted? failed hardware? etc) and thus the error as per rule defined in setup.  If it's working in one manner, but not another; it's likely machine firmware limits that maybe resolved via settings change (in machine firmware) but may also be firmware limits

Try booting from the USB converter again and running lsblk -f, note the file system UUIDs, and compare them to the XXX. Then boot from the SD card slot, try running lsblk -f again (hope it exists in that environment) and check if that filesystem is gone. I'm assuming it can't be found because the minimal boot environment is missing an SD card driver. No idea how to fix it though, thus a comment, not an answer.

Please try this: Load Ubuntu ISO (live session, rather than installed version) on another SD Card. Does the mac boot from it?

Most likely, it is the Mac which cannot boot from its SD card slot (I had an older HP laptop which had the same deficiency).
In that case, this is an Apple design issue and neither an Ubuntu issue (because Ubuntu boots from SD card on capable computers) nor a SD card issue (because your SD card boots when connected with the USB converter).

Since Mac's don't have Busybox built in, the Busybox and the UUID=xxx message have to come from the Ubuntu from the SD card somehow. So it seems the Mac actually did boot from the SD, but the hardware drivers loaded at boot time do not include the SD card slot, so the root filesystem can't be found and mounted, which would explain the message.
